# how to get yii 1 post method working with postman

Tags: php, yii, postman, yii1.x, postman-native-app

I am building restful api for android app using postman, but in postman only get method is working 
complete code is here https://github.com/arvindsinghs/GT/blob/master/apicontroller
this method work if i sent parameters 
     $atts = \Yii::$app->request->get();

[image: method working]

but if it changed it to post method and try to send paramerts in body it is not working 
$atts = \Yii::$app->request->post();

[image: sending in form body]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In Postman don't fill your params into Params Tab, fill them in Body. PostMan consider them there as a sent form

Comment: @noah_abou params are empty in post , see this please https://prnt.sc/sgg5tc

Comment: But it shows that an email was sent and that it's not found in the DB ? Anyway just to be sure, get your postData into a variable and show it to see what's recieving: $postData = yii::$app->request->post(); var_dump($postData); exit;

Comment: @noah_abou did the same as you advised and here array is empty https://prnt.sc/sgg9f3

Comment: Can you post the code the resetPassword Action !

Comment: Also just try to echo anything just to see if the route is actually working: function actionResetPassword(){ echo "test text"; exit();  ...}

Comment: @noah_abou route is working fine https://prnt.sc/sggbux

Comment: Let me see to code then

Comment: @noah_abou, please check code here https://github.com/arvindsinghs/GT/blob/master/apicontroller

Comment: Wierd.. is the crsf disabled ! public  $enableCsrfValidation = false; in the begining of the class. before you do that, add that backslach before yii and try again:   \Yii::$app->request->post()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213839/discussion-between-24-coded-and-noah-abou).

Comment: this means that your API does not recognize content-type: multipart/form-data.  which is normal. form-data values are sent as a block of data ("body part"). e.g. from form requests.

Comment: @JuliusLimson, how can I resolve this content type issue

Comment: @JuliusLimson sent data in multi part https://prnt.sc/sgnxkf